# How to create UI with 1 row, 2 columns?

Tags: flutter

[image: UI]

Above is what I plan to achieve (1 row with 2 products). However, my code below is giving me what I want but with duplicated data.

```
for (var i = 0; i < containers.length - 1; i++) {
      var row = Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          containers[i],
          containers[i + 1],
        ],
      );
      rows.add(row);
    }
```

Here's how I call the method in Widget build:

```
child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  ...displayProducts(),
                ],
              ),
```

The issue with above code is that, it produces `duplicated data` in the `for loop`. How can I produce the same UI with `unique data`?

Comment: Use ```GridView``` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a GridView for this kind of Layout and pass your data list to it

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html

Use the GridView.builder constructor, if you don't know the length of your data.